# Google analytics data for multiple vendors

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a website in which about 200 vendors are registered and I have added google analytics snippet in the website and I want to show each vendor their page views and bounce rate. I don't know the correct way to approach that how each vendor will be able to his data using google analytics api. Can i also use embed api. Can someone suggest me the proper way and example to implement this problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** : ***Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on***

So you can create an analytics report containing your desired metrics and dimensions in Google sheets using Core reporting API [addon](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on). Create a report for each vendor, share it with them and lock the settings sheet.

---

**Option 2** : ***Big Query Api with backend like python***

If you have access to Big query. You can use Big Query Api.

- So you need to create some code in some programming language like
  python.
- Use [Big Query APi](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/) to pull the data and store it into the Google
  sheets. you can create a folder structure in google drive and write simple code to dump this data as google sheets in those folders at Google drive
- Create a ***Cron job*** that would execute your python script on a specific routine say daily or weekly and dump the report on vendors specific folder in google drive as google sheets

Comment: Thank @Tushar but what if I have to show them the data on their dashboard when they login into their dashboard

Comment: @srk You can create multiple reports but you won't be able to hide other data in the view. you give access to particular view via email and share the report but abstraction in data is not possible. Means he can paly around in ga ;)